# How to calculate the intersection point of cedar shakes which share the same angle?

Tags: geometry, angle

I'm sure the post title will be somewhat confusing so I'll try to explain my situation. I'm currently trying to draw, in CAD software, a cross-section through roof structure and I have encountered a geometrical issue which I can't quite work out how to solve. The roof finish is Oak or Cedar Shakes i.e. hand-cut timber rectangles with differing thickness at either end. The size I am using for a single Shake is shown below:

[Single Shake example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbwnA.png)

My problem is relatively simple; as can been seen in the below image, each shake is 125mm apart from its neighbour, and both shakes are then rotated CCW by an unknown angle θ about the pivot points indicated by the red dots. Eventually, when θ is large enough, the opposing point on the bottom surface of Shake A (indicated by a green dot), will intersect with the sloping top surface of Shake B. The reason I am here is to seek advice how to calculate that intersection point?

[Shake arrangement problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gx8yK.png)

n.b. I can manually determine an approximate intersection by process of trial and error applying rotational increments of increasing accuracy, but I would hope that there is some geometrical or computational method to calculate the exact intersection point.

Comment: will you just let them sit one on top of the other in succession ( like when they cover the roof in a row) ? The angle $\theta$ is small. The distance is (of course) approximately $325-125$, but we want the exact arrangement, right?

Comment: Do you want the exact value of angle $\theta$ such that shakes A and B are just touching ?

Comment: @orangeskid Yes, that's correct, its purely just to get the correct appearance instead of just approximating it by eye etc...

Comment: @JeanMarie The angle isn't important, unless that's the only output which can be calculated. My own initial approach was to draw construction geometry in the hope of finding an intersection point e.g. the dashed arc which passes through the green dot. Whether its another arc or line that needs to be provided to calculate the intersection point, I cannot yet determine. If however the answer can only be determined via calculation and not with drawn geometry, I could create a VBA Macro which should be able to implement the correct calculation steps, whatever they may be.

Comment: the interesting thing is that the slab sits on another slab with sits on another one. The one on the very top of the roof perhaps sits on something, or simply flat. In some sense, it also matters how far from the top you are. It's a very small variation. But you get the point. In some sense the angle of the next one depends on the angle of the previous one.  Almost like a recurrence relation. The angles tend to a limit ( they stabilize).

Comment: They can be fixed to battens or a sarking boards, but I purposely did not include any extra detail as it doesn't influence the angle. In reality, the Shakes will come from the right (lower end of the roof) to the left. The angle should remain constant throughout as the first row will have cut Shakes fitted underneath to set the angle. At the ridge (top of the roof), they will simply be cut with a saw as required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shake increases from a thickness of $2$ to a thickness of $10$ at $325$, so it has a slope of $8:325$, or an angle $\varphi_T$,
$$\varphi_T = \arctan\left(\frac{8}{325}\right) \approx 1.4101°$$

The distance between shakes is $125$, and since the initial thickness of the shake, this has a slope of $2:125$, or an angle $\varphi_B$,
$$\varphi_B = \arctan\left(\frac{2}{125}\right) \approx 0.9166°$$

In other words, because $\varphi_T \gt \varphi_B$, it is the far bottom corner of the upper shake that intersects with the next shake, exactly as OP showed.  (Perhaps it was obvious to you, because $\frac{8}{325} \gt \frac{2}{125}$, but I needed to check first.)

If we put the pivot of the top shake at origin, the far bottom corner is then at $x_1(\theta)$, $y_1(\theta)$,
$$\left\lbrace ~ \begin{aligned}
x_1(\theta) &= 325 \cos \theta \\
y_1(\theta) &= 325 \sin \theta \\
\end{aligned} \right . \tag{1}\label{1}$$
If we assume the shakes are at the exact same angle, on the lower shake the point at distance $L$ from the upper initial corner is at $x_2(\theta, L)$, $y_2(\theta, L)$,
$$\left\lbrace ~ \begin{aligned}
x_2(\theta) &= 125 - 2 \sin \theta + L \cos \left(\theta + \varphi_T\right) \\
y_2(\theta) &= 2 \cos\theta + L \sin \left(\theta + \varphi_T\right) \\
\end{aligned} \right . \tag{2}\label{2}$$
Note that with respect to OP's images, right is $x = 1, y = 0$; up is $x = 0, y = 1$; along angle $\theta$ is $x = \cos \theta$, $y = \sin\theta$, and perpendicular to (90° clockwise from) angle $\theta$ is $x = -\sin\theta$, $y = \cos\theta$.

At the intersection, we have a system of two equations in two unknowns ($\theta$ and $L$),
$$\left\lbrace ~ \begin{aligned}
x_1(\theta) &= x_2(\theta, L) \\
y_1(\theta) &= y_2(\theta, L) \\
\end{aligned} \right .$$
i.e.
$$\left\lbrace ~ \begin{aligned}
325 \cos \theta &= 125 - 2 \sin \theta + L \cos \left(\theta + \arctan\left(\frac{8}{325}\right)\right) \\
325 \sin \theta &= 2 \cos\theta + L \sin \left(\theta + \arctan\left(\frac{8}{325}\right)\right) \\
\end{aligned} \right . \tag{3}\label{3}$$
which we need to solve for $0.9166° \le \theta \le 60°$ (any maximum less than $90° - \varphi_T$ works, otherwise $L$ would be infinite or negative), and $0 \le L \le 325$.

I do not know how to solve this algebraically, but numerically it is easy.  Whenever we have a candidate angle $\theta$, we can solve $L$ from the upper equation, i.e.
$$L = \frac{325 \cos \theta - 125 + 2 \sin \theta}{\cos \left(\theta + \arctan\left(\frac{8}{325}\right)\right)}$$
and then compare the left and right sides of the lower equation.  If the left side is greater than the right side, then the angle is too large; if the left side is less than the right side, the angle is too small.  The bisection method (which programmers call 'a binary search') will quickly converge to the solution.

Because I'm faster at typing code than using Octave etc., I wrote this simple Python program,

```
from math import sin, cos, atan, pi

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Separation between shakes
    d = 125

    # Shake total length
    Lmax = 325

    # Shake initial thickness
    tmin = 2

    # Shake final thickness
    tmax = 10

    # Angle of the upper surface of the shake
    a = atan((tmax - tmin)/Lmax)

    # Minimum angle is determined by the shake step
    theta_min = atan(tmin/d)
    # Let's set maximum angle at 60 degrees (60 * pi / 180)
    theta_max = pi / 3.0

    # Bisection method, aka binary search:
    while True:

        # Examine the middle of the interval left
        theta = 0.5*theta_min + 0.5*theta_max

        # Out of precision?
        if theta == theta_min or theta == theta_max:
            break

        # Solve for L
        L = (Lmax * cos(theta) - 125 + tmin*sin(theta)) / cos(theta + a)

        # If L is too long or negative, the angle is too large.
        if L > Lmax or L < 0:
            theta_max = theta
            continue

        # Solve for the y coordinate at the intersection
        y1 = Lmax * sin(theta)
        y2 = tmin * cos(theta) + L * sin(theta + a)

        if y1 < y2:
            # Angle is too small
            theta_min = theta
        elif y1 > y2:
            # Angle is too large
            theta_max = theta
        else:
            break

    print("theta = %.6f degrees" % (theta * 180 / pi))
```

which told me the solution is $\theta = 3.177100°$, or a slope of $\tan(3.177100°) \approx 0.055507759$, or about $1:18.0155$.

If we consider traditional methods, then approximating the angle as a slope of $1:18$ ($\approx 3.17983°$) has less than $0.1\%$ of error.

Comment: Hi Blabbo, very impressive work. The intersection location was only obvious from experience and my previous trial and error approach. I followed your first 2 calculations of the angles (which I can verify from my measure angle tool), however the rest would take some time for me to attempt to digest and understand. Skipping to the end, I have tested your calculated angle and it appears to be 100% correct (at least, visually, at maximum zoom), as you can see with this screen capture: https://i.imgur.com/HdDEBP5.gif

Comment: I was actually beginning to learn Python earlier this year but other things have gotten in the way. Though the syntax is different to VBA (which I am more familiar with) I can follow the steps. The only aspect I am unsure of is how to write the loop for the bisection method. I should probably give it a try and see if the same calculation can be determined within VBA. Many thanks for your reply!

Comment: @SmartSolid: You could use a Do loop, with the repeat condition using a variable initially set to True. Instead of Break, you set that variable to False.  The loop body will become a nested If-Then-Else, with the Else branches just setting the loop repeat condition to False.  Unfortunately, I don't use Windows, and don't have Excel, so I can be of limited help here.

Comment: @SmartSolid: The idea in the other equations is that we have a coordinate system with $(0,0)$ at the lower left corner of the topmost shake. 325 units along the angle $\theta$ is then $(325 \cos \theta, 325 \sin \theta)$.  This is $(x_1, y_1)$.  For the second shake, we need to go "up" by the initial thickness, then along the angle $\theta$ plus the angle of the top surface of the shake.  If it was at origin, that would be $\bigl(-2 \sin \theta + L \cos (\theta + \varphi_T), 2 cos \theta + L \sin (\theta + \varphi_T)\bigr)$.  But since it is 125 units to the left, we add $(125, 0)$ to it.

Comment: @SmartSolid: Because of the angle, we don't know *exactly* (mathematically exactly) how much $L$ is, although we know $L \approx 125$.  The reason I didn't bother about it, is because I knew that with two equations –– both $x$ coordinates having to match, and both $y$ coordinates having to match, at the intersection point –– I can have two independent variables –– $\theta$ and $L$ –– and still solve the system of equations.  If I had constructed the equations with an approximate $L$, I either would not find any solutions, or the solutions would have been approximate.

Comment: @SmartSolid: For the numerical solution finding, I saw that I could solve for $L$ in the equation for when the $x$ coordinates match, for any given (sane) $\theta$, from $325 \cos \theta = 125 - 2 \sin \theta + L \cos(\theta + \varphi_T)$.  Then, fitting back $\theta$ and $L$ into $y_1$ and $y_2$, I can check if the shakes "overlap": they are separate when $y_1 > y_2$, they overlap when $y_1 < y_2$, and intersect at one point when $y_1 = y_2$.  This applies to angles $-90° + \varphi_T \lt \theta \lt 90° - \varphi_T$, i.e. the shakes are not too far off horizontal.  Simples!

Comment: For the most part, I followed what you were doing. It was only the variable L which I was unsure what it was representing; I would likely understand it easier if I saw a diagram which showed what it was calculating. However, I was able to convert the code successfully: https://i.imgur.com/GLJjrXh.png . Purely out of curiosity, would your same bisection approach work with an object with a curved top surface? I'm thinking of clay tiles which have a slight curve e.g. https://www.total-contractor.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/air-path-through-eaves-ventilator-785x1024.jpeg.

Comment: @SmartSolid: Yes, but if you want to solve this for any tile whose upper and lower surface you can describe with $y(x)$ curves, I have a similar but better method.  The idea is that we use a coordinate system where both tiles are horizontal, and one's lower corner is at origin.  We just move the other's lower corner (keeping it horizontal), until they touch but do not overlap.  The angle the line through their lower corners make with horizontal is then $\theta$.  It too would use bisection in $\theta$, just have simpler equations.

Comment: Hopefully [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uzdyj.png) explains the idea.  Yellow is the substructure, red point is origin, yellow is the point we "move", $d$ is the slate separation distance, and $\theta$ is the slant angle.  The tiles always stay horizontal, so if we can describe their upper and lower surfaces, a similar function can find the $\theta$ given $d$, or alternatively $d$ given $\theta$.  It is a bit more involved, because we *should* check the gray area at each bisection test to be sure, and not just the very corner, but it is not a big deal.

Comment: I have written a much simpler answer than the first answer I gave.

Answer (score 2):

Let the origin be at the bottom left corner of Shake B (the right one).  The coordinates of the bottom right corner is

$ P = (325, 0) $

It follows that the coordinates of the corresponding point in the unrotated Shake A is

$ Q = (200, 0) $

The top of the unrotated Shake B has the equation

$ y = 2 + \dfrac{ 10 - 2}{325} x = 2 + \dfrac{8}{325} x $

Rotating point $Q$ about the point $(-125, 0)$, it becomes

$Q' = (-125 + 325 \cos \theta , 325 \sin \theta ) $

And the top of Shake B after rotation about the origin, has the equation

$ ( -\sin \theta x' + \cos \theta y' ) = 2 + \dfrac{8}{325} (\cos  \theta x' + \sin \theta y') $

We want $Q'$ to lie on this line, so

$ -\sin \theta (-125+ 325 \cos \theta) + \cos \theta (325 \sin \theta) = 2 + \dfrac{8}{325} ( \cos \theta (-125 + 325 \cos \theta ) + \sin \theta ( 325 \sin \theta )  ) $

Simplifying and re-arranging,

$  125 \sin \theta = 2 + \dfrac{8}{325} (-125 \cos \theta + 325 ) $

$  \dfrac{40}{13} \cos \theta + 125 \sin \theta = 10 $

Whose acute solution is

$  \theta = 0.05545086 = 3.1771^\circ$

Comment: [+1] Interesting solution. On my side, I just provided a second much simpler solution than the first one.

Answer (score 1):

This was my first answer. In fact, I have found afterwhile very simple explanations, so different from these ones that I have given them in a [second answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4579017/305862).

---

Initial answer:

The formulas giving the coordinates of the touching point are simple: first compute

$$t_0=\tan^{-1}\frac{c-a}{b}\tag{1}$$

followed by

$$t_1=\sin^{-1}[\tfrac{1}{d}(a \cos(t_0) + b \sin(t_0)]-t_0\tag{2}$$

Finally giving the coordinates of the touching point:

$$x=b \cos(t_1), \ y = b \sin(t_1)$$

which, with your numerical values :

$$a=2, b=325, c=10, d=125$$

gives the result:

$$x\approx 324.50, \ \ \ y \approx 18.01$$

---

Why that ? let us explain it using complex numbers geometry with the notations of the figure here (which is not at all at the given scale because my purpose was to obtain general formulas and be able to check them):

[image]

Let $t_1$ be the *common* angle of the bases of the first and second shakes wrt to the horizontal reference.

The angle of line segment $AC$ wrt horizontal line $OD$ is $t_1$ plus a certain angle $t_0$ given by $\tan t_0=\frac{c-a}{b}$ (which is equivalent to formula (1) above ; proof: consider right triangle $AA'C$ where $A'$ is the orthogonal projection of $A$ onto $BC$)

The complex expressions of points $A$ and $B$ are

$$A=aie^{it_1} \ \ \text{and} \ \ B=be^{i(t_0+t_1)}$$

Now, how can we express the constraint saying that point $B$ touches the other piece of wood ? By expressing that this point can be written in two ways and equating these two ways:

$$\text{there exists a real number} \  r \ \ \text{such that} \ \ be^{i t_1}=\underbrace{d+aie^{i t_1}+ r e^{i (t_1+t_0)}}_{\text{in the second shake}}\tag{4}$$

which is equivalent to :

$$r=(b-ai)e^{-it_0}-de^{-i(t_1+t_0)}\tag{5}$$

$r$ being a real number, a fact that allows us to equate (5) and its conjugate expression:

$$(b-ai)e^{-it_0}-de^{-i(t_1+t_0)}=(b+ai)e^{it_0}-de^{i(t_1+t_0)}\tag{6}$$

from which we deduce:

$$-2ib \sin(t_0)-2ia \cos(t_0) = -2id \sin(t_1+t_0) \tag{7}$$

$$b \sin(t_0)+a \cos(t_0) = d \sin(t_1+t_0) \tag{8}$$

Formula (8) gives almost immediately formula (2).

Remark: I am almost sure that relationship (8) can be established in a simpler way...

Comment: I appreciate the effort and explanation of your solution. I am not so mathematically inclined to know which of the 2 solutions is superior, yet it seems they both return the correct information which I can use, either as an angle or coordinates. For anyone doubting this solution, or like me, does not have a deep understanding of the theory and formulae provided, perhaps this image will graphically confirm its validity https://i.imgur.com/7ybs3vv.png

Comment: Indeed the coordinates of the point matches our computations !

Comment: Besides, I just found (as I was expecting) a much simpler way to explain the formulas I have obtained, with simpler mathematics ! I am going to modify my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a second solution of mine to this issue.

I have chosen to give it separately because it uses a technique which is very different from the first one, using much simpler (and visual) explanations.

Consider the image below and its notations.

[image]

Let us define angle $t_0$ by :

$$\tan t_0 = \frac{c-a}{b} \ \iff \ t_0=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{c-a}{b}\right)\tag{1}$$

Elementary angle-chasing gives the indicated values of the angles in triangle $EFG$.

Sine law (proportionality of sidelengths to the sines of opposite angles) in triangle $EFG$ gives :

$$\frac{c}{\sin(t_0+t_1)}=\frac{d}{\cos t_0}$$

$$\sin(t_0+t_1)=\frac{c}{d} \cos t_0$$

finaly giving

$$t_1=\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{c}{d} \cos t_0 - t_0\right)\tag{2}$$

Formulas (1) and (2) provides all our needs, because, having angle $t_1$, we are able to conclude that tangency point $E$ has coordinates:

$$(x_E=b \cos t_1 , y_E=b \sin t_1)\tag{3}$$

Using the numerical values

$$a=2,b=325,c=10,d=125$$

(3) gives :

$$(x_E \approx 324,5005 \ , \ y_E \approx 18.0123)$$